# youtube v3 api request timeout

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm working on project that uses the YouTube api v3 with the Google .net client libary.

It's done, however sometimes it takes long time to respond when getting a video-list from playlist id.  When this happens, it gives error "bad request" after 1 minute and tells me request timed out.

Is there any way to increase the request timeout  or another solution for this problem?

```
List<YTVideo> videos = new List<YTVideo>();
var searchRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
                searchRequest.PlaylistId = playlistId;
                searchRequest.MaxResults = 1;
                var searchResponse = await searchRequest.ExecuteAsync();
                var playlistItemsInfo = searchResponse.Items.FirstOrDefault();
// to get videos from playlistItemsInfo
foreach (var searchResult in searchResponse.Items)
                    {
                        var videoSearchRequest = youtubeService.Videos.List("snippet, statistics, contentDetails");
                        videoSearchRequest.Id = searchResult.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId;
                        videoSearchRequest.MaxResults = 1;
                        var videoSearchResponse = videoSearchRequest.Execute();
                        var video = videoSearchResponse.Items.FirstOrDefault();
                        if (video != null)
                        {
                            YTVideo yTVideo = new YTVideo
                            {
                                Title = video.Snippet.Title,
                                VideoId = video.Id,
                                Image = video.Snippet.Thumbnails.Maxres != null ? video.Snippet.Thumbnails.Maxres.Url : video.Snippet.Thumbnails.High.Url,
                                IsSelected = true
                            };
                            videos.Add(yTVideo);
                        }
                    }
```

My problem happens in `searchResponse` when I execute search the request.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  then edit your question include your code and describe any issues you are having with your solution.   Without seeing your code we cant help you find a solution to your issue.

Comment: Thank you DalmTo,
i edit my question and put my code in.

Comment: searchRequest.MaxResults = 1;  <-- increase max results is 5 i would set it to 50

Comment: ok but i get playlist and video by id so no need to increase max results

Comment: The minimum is 5 for max result on that call. Im not seeing any other issues with your code.

Comment: Is highly likely that the timeouts are due to a poor Internet connection that is at your disposal. In my experience, the YouTube Data API responds dutifully and timely; thus, I recommend that you look for network issues on your own end of the connection.